# Analytic max() and partitioning clause

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

After several tries, I can't seem to grasp Oracle Analytic functions, so I turn here again, with a new problem:
I have the following table:

```
create table TConcordance (
CurrentData     varchar2(6),
CurrentStart    date,
PredictorData   varchar2(6),
TimeFrame       varchar2(3),
PredictorStart  date,
PatternLength   number, -- l
PatternShift    number, -- h
KTau            number,
SRho            number,
Gini            number,
WeakC           number);
```

A Primary Key is created on (CurrentData, CurrentStart, PredictorData,TimeFrame).

Here is my problem: I need to retrieve CurrentStart and (in a separate query) PredictorStart for those records with the highest value of SRho within any combination of (CurrentData, TimeFrame, CurrentStart).
Within a larger Select Union All, I have the following subquery that works as intended, and returns Max(SRho) for every possible CurrentStart:

```
select t.CurrentData, t.TimeFrame, t.CurrentStart, max(t.SRho)
from TConcordance t, AllHistory ah
where t.CurrentData=ah.Symbol and t.TimeFrame=ah.TimeFrame
group by t.CurrentData, t.TimeFrame, t.CurrentStart
```

Now, here's my problem: For each of the rows returned by the query above, I need to retrieve the PredictorStart column, too. I tried the following:

```
select distinct t.CurrentData, t.TimeFrame, t.CurrentStart,
    max(t.SRho) over (partition by t.CurrentData, t.TimeFrame, t.CurrentStart
        order by t.CurrentStart) "MaxSRho", t.PredictorData, t.PredictorStart
```

Unfortunately, this seems to consider the added columns as part of the distinct clause, therefore returning all the rows in the table...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `PredictorData` is part of the primary key, so it's going to be different for every row in `t`. So it's correct that it shows all rows, surely? Nothing to do with the analytics directly, you'd see the same thing with the original version if you added those columns to the `group by`. Or do you mea you want to show the `Predictor*` columns that correspond to the `max(t.SRHo)` value you get?

Comment: @AlexPoole, Indeed, I want to show PredictorData and PredictorStart that correspond to the max(t.SRHo) value I get from the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PredictorData` is part of the primary key, so it's going to be different for every row in `t`. So it's correct that it shows all rows from that table. This isn't related to the analytic function specifically, you'd see the same thing with the original version if you added those columns to the group by.

If you want to see the `PredictorData` and `PredictorStart` from the same row that provides the highest `SHro`, then `max()` is the wrong function to use here. You can get what you want with `first_values()` instead:

```
select distinct t.CurrentData, t.TimeFrame, t.CurrentStart,
    first_value(t.SRho)
        over (partition by t.CurrentData, t.TimeFrame, t.CurrentStart
            order by t.SRho desc) "MaxSRho",
    first_value(t.PredictorData)
        over (partition by t.CurrentData, t.TimeFrame, t.CurrentStart
            order by t.SRho desc) "PredictorData",
    first_value(t.PredictorStart)
        over (partition by t.CurrentData, t.TimeFrame, t.CurrentStart
            order by t.SRho desc) "PredictorStart"
from AllHistory ah
join TConcordance t on t.CurrentData=ah.Symbol and t.TimeFrame=ah.TimeFrame
```

Comment: +1 simply for being able to work out that this is what the OP required :)  I'd add another +1 if I could.

Comment: @Alex-Poole: Once again, thanks for your help, this is exactly what I was looking for! :-)